# How to Parse Nested XML to nested Array?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, soap

How to pass this xml into array to use in soap function. like

```
$res=$client->OTA_HotelDestinationsRQ($myarray);

<OTA_HotelDestinationsRQ Version="1.0">
      <POS>
        <Source>
             <UniqueId Id="username:password" />           
        </Source>
      </POS>
      <DestinationInformation LanguageCode="EN" />
</OTA_HotelDestinationsRQ>
```

Comment: why do you have to have in an array? What's wrong with using the tree hierarchies offered by DOM or SimpleXml? And which of the [existing questions asking the same](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xml+to+array+php) have you searched?

Comment: i want to pass array as a soap request

Comment: i got response when i use the code like $res=$client->_call("OTA_HotelDestinationsRQ",array($xml)); how to pass data array in that OTA_HotelDestinationsRQ function

Comment: What data needs to be harvested?  Desired array format?

Comment: I have problems to understand your question. Which soap client are you using? Which SOAP API are you using? What is `$array`, can you add the output of `var_dump($array)` to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code like this:

```
function process( DOMNode $node){
    // Special handling for character data
    if( $node instanceof DOMCharacterData){
        return $node->data;
    }

    // Has only text inside:
    if( ($node->childNodes->length == 1) && ($node->childNodes->item(0)->nodeName == '#text') && ($node->childNodes->item(0) instanceof DOMCharacterData)){
        return $node->childNodes->item(0)->data;
    }

    // Get all attributes
    $result = array();
    foreach( $node->attributes as $item){
        $result[ $item->name] = $item->value;
    }

    // Go trough all child nodes
    foreach($node->childNodes as $sub){
        $result[$sub->nodeName] = process( $sub);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And the result:

```
Array
(
    [Version] => 1.0
    [POS] => Array
        (
            [Source] => Array
                (
                    [UniqueId] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => username:password
                        )

                )

        )

    [DestinationInformation] => Array
        (
            [LanguageCode] => EN
        )

    [text] => text
)
```

Useful documentation links:

- [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)
- [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)
- [`DOMNameNodeMap`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnamednodemap.item.php)
- [`DOMCharacterData`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domcharacterdata.php)